# Please help me understand one line of code

Tags: javascript, mirth

I've inherited a series of mirth channels that I need to modify but don't understand everything that has been done.

Yes, I could rewrite them 'my way' but time is short so, if anyone can explain what some of the code does that might be a real life saver.

The code I have inherited makes extensive use of '*::' (see example below).

`tmp.*::['Body'].*::['SavePathologyResults'].*::['request'].*::['PathologyResults'].*::['SavePathologyResultRequest'][index] = newWCFNode;`

While I get a general feel from this, what exactly does '*::' mean/do?

Thanks in anticipation...

(For context, 'tmp' is an XML SOAP envelope)

Comment: Not even sure this is valid JavaScript! Can you give us a bit more context around this line of code?

Comment: That’s E4X, wow. What a throwback.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [E4X (ECMAScript for XML)](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/ECMA-357.pdf), `::` is the syntax for qualified identifiers (11.1.2). `*::['Body']` (or the equivalent `*::Body`) is the `Body` identifier in any namespace (11.1.3). Accessing it as the property of an XML or XMLList object means getting a new XMLList of all children with that identifier as a node name (11.2.1).

So, that statement gets `<Body>` elements in `tmp`, then `<SavePathologyResults>` elements in those `<Body>` elements, then …, then `<SavePathologyResultRequest>` elements in those `<PathologyResults>` elements, and replaces the `index`th `<SavePathologyResultRequest>` with `newWCFNode` (11.6.2) – where all of the aforementioned (and aforeunmentioned) elements could belong to any namespace.

Comment: Thanks Ry-, no wonder I couldn't find the answer in any javascript sources.